# If a value appears less than 3 times in every 10 cells of a column then replace these values with another value

Tags: excel

In a column I have more than 50000 values. Many of these are missing and are designated as "NA". I would like to run through every 10 rows of this column and if there less than 3 missing values, i.e. 1 or 2 "NA" to replace them with zero "0".

I have struggled a lot with this and the furthest I have managed to get is this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF((OFFSET(A$1,(ROW()-ROW(A$1))*10,,10,)),$A$1)<3,A1="NA"),0,A1)
```

This is not correct.

With the aforementioned formula I get this result (which is not what I want):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQRxQ.jpg]

The desired result would be this:

[image: photo]

Comment: You can do this fairly easily if you're willing to use VBA. Look into excel vba loops as a good starting point.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the count to be for the ten preceding lines or the ten following lines. i.e. for line 12, do you want to know if there are 3 or more "NA"s in lines 3-12 or lines 12-21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1 and copy down:

```
=IF(OR(A1<>"NA",COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/10)*10+1):INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/10)*10+10),"NA")>2),A1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks a lot!!